# how to select multiple folders in scilab

Tags: scilab

I am looking for a function to select multiple directories in Scilab. I have found a similar function in Matlab Central uipickfiles.m. But is there a simpler and similar function in Scilab.
If it is not already available I am trying to write a function for the same.

Any suggestions/guidance is very appreciated.

regards
Devaraj

Comment: Could you please specify your question further? Do you want a GUI, in which you select multiple folders?

Comment: Yes i want a GUI like UIGETDIR GUI to select multiple folders.

Answer (score 0):

Since the built-in GUI does not allow you to select more directories, here is a workaround in 3 steps:

1. first select a "parent" directory, in which you want to select
   multiple subdirectories
2. list the subdirectories
3. choose multiple subdirectories with an `x_choices` dialog

E.g.:

```
directory=uigetdir();  //select the parent directory, in which you want to choose multiple subdirectories!

allfiles=dir(directory);   //all files in the directory
onlydirectories=allfiles.name(find(allfiles.isdir));  //select only the directories

if size(onlydirectories,"*")>1 then   //there are 2 or more directory
  L=list(list(onlydirectories(1),1,["-","+"]));  //build the lists for x_choices:
  for i=2:size(onlydirectories,"*")
    L(i)=list(onlydirectories(i),1,["-","+"]);
  end

  rep=x_choices("Select directories with +",L);   //multiple choices with toggle buttons

  selecteddirectories=onlydirectories(find(rep==2));
  disp(selecteddirectories,"selecteddirectories:");

  selectedfullpath=directory+selecteddirectories+"\";
  disp(selectedfullpath,"selectedfullpath:");
end
```

Not too pretty solution but it kind of works...